# SVN log not showing all the revisions made to a file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've started using SVN before a few weeks. I am facing a weird problem right now. We have a file, which was added by me to the repository. Another developer checked it out yesterday, made some modifications to it, and comitted it to the repository. Today, I made some modifications to that file and comitted it to the repository. But it didn't ask me to merge the changes when I comitted that file, so now I only have the version which I had modified, and the changes done by the other developer are not even showing up in the log.

What am I missing here? How should I go about merging both the changes? We are using TortoiseSVN as a client.

EDIT: All other developers are able to see the log entry in their SVN clients!! So, it seems that the commit was properly done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you should have been in this situation, quoth the [Turtle Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/):

> **Locally changed, and out of date** 
>       The file has been changed both in the working directory and in the repository. An svn commit of the file will fail with an “out-of-date” error. The file should be updated first; an svn update command will attempt to merge the public changes with the local changes. If Subversion can't complete the merge in a plausible way automatically, it leaves it to the user to resolve the conflict.

I would verify two things:

1. The other developer's work was actually committed correctly. If the log does not reflect these changes, I'd guess that it might be the case that they were not committed properly.
2. That your working copy wasn't updated/merged without you realizing it.

Answer (score 7):

We had this same thing happen just now. Everyone else sees the latest revision, except the person who committed it. Repairing his svn directory didn't help... Show All didn't help....

Turns out that when you issue the Show Log command, you have 3 option boxes:

- Show Only Affected Paths
- Stop on Copy/Rename
- Include Merged Versions

When he selected the Include Merged Versions box, TortoiseSVN retrieved pretty much the same set of revisions again in the Show Log, but this time included the latest revision! Unchecking the box didn't remove the latest version.

My theory is that Tortoise caches the SVN info locally, and uses that instead of reaching across the net. Changing a major option forced it to re-read the SVN log history.

Comment: I just had this problem and solved by cleaning TortoiseSVN log cache.

Comment: The clear log cache setting can be found at TortoiseSVN->Settings->Saved Data->Log messages (Show log dialog).

Comment: On the Show log screen, you can press SHIFT+F5 (or SHIFT + refresh button, I think) to refresh the log and log messages

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Thanks, that fixed it for me.  (I can't believe deleting log messages fixes a problem where tortoise is hiding updates to a repository even after deleting the whole tree and checking out again).

Answer (score 6):

Right click on desktop, You will see tortoiseSVN, click on tortoiseSVN->Settings. Go to the Saved data and clear the log mentioned into picture. 
Please let me know if you have any additional questions. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as your working copy isn't properly updated. I'm not familiar with TortoiseSVN, but try to update your working copy and check the log again. Your changes has probably been merged silently.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, It was not showing the log history and its resolved now by clearing the Saved data from setting of SVN

Comment: please elaborate your answer